# Can "doing so" refer to a conditional clause?

Tags: grammar, tense, reference

What "doing so" should refer to is the fact that he had mastered English but here what I have is "he had not mastered English". Is this okay?

> He would not have been able to go from being broke to being a
> multi-millionaire if he **had not mastered English**. **Doing so**
> created opportunities for him to network in Facebook groups with
> American businessmen and be inspired by American hustle culture.

Do I need to turn the conditional tense into a normal tense? I actually I want to use the conditional tense.

> He was able to go from being broke to being a multi-millionaire only
> because he **had mastered English**. **Doing so** created
> opportunities for him to network in Facebook groups with American
> businessmen and be inspired by American hustle culture.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct and natural.

This is because in your first example, you're using an *unreal conditional*, which means he *did* master English, even though the clause is in the negative.